# How to override Show instance of some basic types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, overriding

I'm writting some programs in Haskell, dealing with a lot of basic types like Word32/Word64 etc..
I use ghci to test the functions frequently, see the results in terminal.

To be convenient and fast, I always show data in hexadecimal e.g.

```
data Human = M Int | F Int
instance Show Human where
    show M x = printf "man, age %d" x
    show F x = printf "woman, age %d" x
```

but I want **basic types** to be showed in hexadecimal (espacially in ghci).
I found instance declaration cannot be overridden.
and I **don't** want to warp all of them up like:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
instance Show MyInt where
    ...
```

It looks a little bit stupid.

Can I modify some code in the package `base` for ghc?
I just want everything becoming "hex". I just want ghci showing "hex". how could I achieve it?

### EDIT

Since all of us agree that override Show is not proper and impractical,
**Any answer of "better ways to show Numeric in hexadecimal in ghci" is welcomed.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be abusing the `Show` instance. It's not really meant for formatting. If you want to show something in hexadecimal, just use a function to do the conversion. For example, you can use `showHex` from `Numeric` to make a small helper like this:

```
> import Numeric
Numeric> let hex x = showHex x ""
Numeric> hex 123456
"1e240"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close. Using `hex` will save more time.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way to achieve this without `newtype`s; instances cannot be overriden.

If you really want this, I would suggest defining your own typeclass, `ShowHex`, like `Show` but with all the instances printing in hex. However, I would consider your `Show` instance incorrect; `Show` instances are designed for debugging and serialisation, and should output syntactically valid code.<sup>1</sup> Yours doesn't, so I would suggest either defining your own typeclass for displaying these values, or simply using a function.

Modifying the code to base for this is impractical; not only would this change in semantics for the instances break a lot of packages, but it'd be a huge pain to get GHC to actually use your modified version.

<sup>1</sup> Ideally, the code they produce should be *semantically* valid Haskell that produces a value comparing equal to `show`'s input, but this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Can I tell ghci to use ShowHex to show rather than Show? I want ghci to show in hex.

Comment: No, but you could define `p = putStrLn . myShow` and prefix your lines with `p $`. (By the way, I updated my answer since you posted your comment.)

Comment: Thanks. I think so. touch base package sounds horrible. `p` is practical enough for me. :)

Comment: @Nybble You can use `:set -interactive-print=myPrint` to override the default print function in ghci. Put it in `~/.ghci` to override it always.

Comment: As for "instances cannot be overriden", I was a bit surprized I was able to define my own instance for [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:ZipList) (with a shorter representation than an automatic `deriving Show` would give) although `Show (Ziplist a)` instance is listed on hackage! That is probably because `Control.Applicative` doesn't define such an instance, it must be in `Text.Show`...

Answer (score 2):

One extreme solution would be to use `{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}`, and import your own "Prelude" instead. That would probably be a lot more work than it's worth for your case, though.

Comment: If the goal was to change the default printing behavior of GHCi, that won't work as it's hardwired to use the standard `Show` class.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with @ehird and @hammar that this could be abused. In the case of wanting some numbers to always show as hex, I think it's reasonable because "0xff" is a legitimate representation of a number. So this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module HexNumber where

import Numeric
import Text.Read
import qualified Text.Read.Lex as L

newtype HexInt a = HexInt { int :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Num, Enum)

instance (Show a, Integral a) => Show (HexInt a) where 
  show hi = "0x" ++ showHex (int hi) ""

instance (Num a) => Read (HexInt a) where
-- Couldn't figure out how to write this instance so just copy/paste from Text.Read
  readPrec     = readNumber convertInt
  readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
  readList     = readListDefault

readNumber :: Num a => (L.Lexeme -> ReadPrec a) -> ReadPrec a
readNumber convert =
  parens
  ( do x <- lexP
      case x of
        L.Symbol "-" -> do y <- lexP
                            n <- convert y
                            return (negate n)

        _   -> convert x
  )

convertInt :: Num a => L.Lexeme -> ReadPrec a
convertInt (L.Number n)
| Just i <- L.numberToInteger n = return (fromInteger i)
convertInt _ = pfail
```

Now I can:

```
> let x = 10 :: HexInt Int
> x
0xa
> x * 2
0x14
> let x = 10 :: HexInt Integer
> x
0xa
> x * 2
0x14
> read "0xa" :: HexInt Int
0xa
> read "10" :: HexInt Int
0xa
```

This seems very useful to me working with low-level stuff a lot. Maybe I'll put it on Hackage.