# Make GHCi to print in decimal form.

Tags: haskell, ghci

Sometimes scientific notation leads me on to think that my result is incorrect, until I see the '**e**' (e.g 2.1474027456**e**-2).

How do I make GHCi to print in decimal form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override Show instance of some basic types in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288883/how-to-override-show-instance-of-some-basic-types-in-haskell)

Comment: Closely related: [*Haskell - how to avoid scientific notation in decimal output*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37006362/2751851) (arguably not a dupl*cate because it doesn't concern GHCi output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `printf`

```
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude> printf "%f\n" (0.0000001 * exp 1)
0.0000002718281828459045
```

Works for a list of numbers too:

```
Prelude> map (printf "%f" :: Float -> String) $ take 10 $ iterate (* exp (-1)) 1.0
["1.0","0.36787945","0.1353353","0.049787074","0.018315641","0.006737948","0.0024787525","0.0009118821","0.00033546268","0.00012340983"]
```