# How to change Ord instance for tuple of type (String, Int) without declaring a new data?

Tags: sorting, haskell

I'm trying to sort a list of type `[(String, Int)]`. By default, it is sorting by Strings and then Ints (if the Strings are equal). I want it to be the opposite — first, compare Ints and then if equal compare the Strings. Additionally, I don't want to switch to `[(Int, String)]`.

I found a way to do so by defining an instance, but it only works for my own data type, which I don't want to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288914/5499914

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya If you believe a question is a duplicate, please flag it as a duplicate (or vote to close, if you have enough rep).

Comment: @amalloy Would have, don't worry. That only answers half the question, about overriding the instance; there's more to be said here.

Answer (score 13):

You can sort with [**`sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy):

```
import Data.List(sortBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

orderSwap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
orderSwap = sortBy (comparing swap)
```

or with [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn):

```
import Data.List(sortOn)
import Data.Ord(comparing)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

orderSwap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
orderSwap = sortOn swap
```

Or we can just perform two swaps and sort the intermediate result:

```
import Data.Tuple(swap)

orderSwap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
orderSwap = map swap . sort . map swap
```

This is of course not the "standard ordering". If you want to define  an inherent order differently than one that is derived by the instances already defined, you should define your own type.

For example with:

```
newtype MyType = MyType (String, Int) deriving Eq

instance Ord MyType where
    compare (MyType a) (MyType b) = comparing swap a b
```

Comment: Your first one can also be spelled `sortBy (comparing swap)`.

Comment: Or just `sortOn swap`.

Comment: For what it's worth: if performance matters, `sortBy` will almost certainly be faster than `sortOn` because `swap` is cheap. The `sortBy` version will probably allocate more memory but retain less.

Answer (score 0):

The `newtype` is the usual way to define a new instance for an existing type.

Although you will still need to have a constructor for a newtype type there is no computational overhead. The compiler will remove the newtype wrapper opposed to defining a type with `data`.